# WPF control name with . in it.

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf control and i want to set the name to contain .
When trying to do this I get an exception thrown that:

```
{"'Communications.WCF.URL' is not a valid value for property 'Name'."}
```

Im assuming this is because of the . in the name.

I cant see any other attributes I could use to store the Communications.WCF.URL value but I thought id check.

Please let me know if you require anymore information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Control`'s name cannot contain periods as you've discovered. You could replace the periods with underscores. Or you could use the `Tag` attribute to store the URL. It is not unusual for the `Tag` attribute to be used for storing extraneous information.

Answer (score 1):

If that is how you want to name your control, you will need to change your namespace to be Communications.WCF, where URL is your control name (If I understand correctly).

Answer (score 1):

The name of a control is also the name of the object that represents the control in code. That is the reason why `.` (period) isn't a valid character for a control name.

Are you perhaps confusion control `Name` with `Caption` attribute?